# Creating a new DataRow into an existing DataTable

Tags: c#

Greets!  I am trying to create a DataRow and add it to an existing DataSet/DataTable.  The problem I am running into is that the tables do not seem to be propagating correctly.  I know the table exists yet it won't give me anything but null in return.  Any ideas?

Code:

```
var TownDataSet = new DataSet("newDataSet");
var checkDataSet = new DataSet();
var checkDataTable = new DataTable();
var dataTableName = "someDataSet";
checkDataSet = TownDataSet.Clone();
checkDataTable = TownDataSet.Tables[dataTableName];
Console.WriteLine("STEP 4 " + checkDataSet.DataSetName);
Console.WriteLine("STEP 5 " + checkDataSet.Tables.Count);
Console.WriteLine("STEP 6 " + checkDataTable.TableName);
```

Error when I get to Step 6:

```
STEP 4 newDataSet
STEP 5 7
DataTableInsertTemp: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Comment: checkDataTable.`checkDataSet`.Tables.Count, checkDataSet isn't there, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's analyze:

```
var TownDataSet = new DataSet("newDataSet");
var checkDataSet = new DataSet();
var checkDataTable = new DataTable();
var dataTableName = "someDataSet";
checkDataSet = TownDataSet.Clone();
checkDataTable = TownDataSet.Tables[dataTableName];
```

Where:

- checkDataSet is a new DataSet containing 0 tables;
- checkDataTable is a new DataTable contained in no DataSet

So:

- TownDataSet.Tables is an empty collection
- TownDataSet.Tables[dataTableName] is null

Try this instead:

```
   var dataTableName = "someDataSet";
   var TownDataSet = new DataSet("newDataSet");
   var checkDataSet = new DataSet();

   /* add a new DataTable to the DataSet.Tables collection */
   checkDataSet.Tables.Add(new DataTable(dataTableName));

    /* maybe you need to add some columns too */
    checkDataSet.Tables[dataTableName].Columns.Add(new DataColumn("columnA", typeof(int)));
    checkDataSet.Tables[dataTableName].Columns.Add(new DataColumn("columnB", typeof(string)));

    /* create and initialize a new DataRow for the Tables[dataTableName] table */
    var r = TownDataSet.Tables[dataTableName].NewRow();
    r["columnA"] = 1;
    r["columnB"] = "Some value";

    /* add it to the Tables[dataTableName].Rows collection */
    TownDataSet.Tables[dataTableName].Rows.Add(r);
```

**EDIT**

There are several ways to map a db into a dataset. I can suggest you a few:

- [POCO  - Plain Old CLR Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object). That is create an entity class for each table, mapping the table's fields into the class's properties.
- [Object-Relational Mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping). It is a framework layer that maps database tables into classes. A C# implementation is [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/).
- [ADO.NET Tables Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/229sz0y5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can use the ADO.NET capabilities to import the database's tables schema definition into a dataset using the DataAdapter class.

Here a **basic** implementation:

```
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.Tables.Add(new DataTable("myTable"));
    da.FillSchema(ds.Tables["mytable"], SchemaType.Source);


    var dataTableName = "someDataSet";
    var TownDataSet = new DataSet("newDataSet");
    var checkDataSet = new DataSet();

    /* add a new DataTable to the DataSet.Tables collection */
    checkDataSet.Tables.Add(new DataTable(dataTableName));

    /*
     * Fit the sql statement and the connection string depending on your scenario
     * Set the *Command, *Connection and *DataAdapter actual provider
     */
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from myTable");
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("my connection string");
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

    cmd.Connection = conn;
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;

    /* that's it: the datatable is now mapped with the corresponding db table structure */
    da.FillSchema(checkDataSet.Tables[dataTableName], SchemaType.Source);
```

Comment: The part I am failing to understand is how we will propagate the correct schema into the DataSet/Table

Comment: What do you mean by 'correct schema'? Is there a database structure you would to replicate in the DataSet?

Comment: ADC - Yes there is a pre-existing structure that I would like passed down into the DataTable.

Comment: It turns out it was code in another location causing the issue.  Thank you for the assistance.